# Proper CPython String Concatenation

Tags: python, string

Last night I was at a [Boston Python Meetup](http://meetup.bostonpython.com/events/25396721/) that described various Python implementations. Part of the discussion included string concatenation.

Apparently for CPython there is less heap fragmentation if strings are concatenated starting with an empty string and then using join.

Is this an OK way to construct a string

```
sql_statement = "select count(*) " + \
    "from ept_inv e " + \
    "where e.ept_type =  " + str(in_row[cs.DeviceType]) + " " + \
    "and e.inv_id = " + str(in_row[cs.EndpointID]) + " ; "
```

or should I have set `sql_statement` to `""` and then joined each piece?
Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting parameters directly into SQL statements anyway. *Always* use placeholders and pass the values as the `parameters` argument to `cursor.execute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@robert has a very good point of using `format()` for a string. 
Another way of concatenating strings is:

```
s = ('select count(*)'
     'from ept_inv e'
     'where e.ept_type = {device_type}'
     'and e.inv_id = {endpoint_id};')

sql_statement = sql_statement_format.format(
                    device_type=in_row[cs.DeviceType],
                    endpoint_id=in_row[cs.EndpointId])
```

In fact, in Python, using parenthesis like this is preferred to truncating lines via `\`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a multi-line string literal with `.format`:

```
sql_statement_format = """
    select count(*)
    from ept_inv e
    where e.ept_type = {device_type} 
    and e.inv_id = {endpoint_id};
"""
sql_statement = sql_statement_format.format(
    device_type=in_row[cs.DeviceType],
    endpoint_id=in_row[cs.EndpointId])
```

You need to properly sanitize your SQL queries, or [bad things can happen](https://www.xkcd.com/327/).  Is there any reason you're not using the Python database API?

Comment: I found mysqldb and started using that.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the [Python performance tips](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation) for advice on string concatenation.

> Avoid:
>
> ```
> out = "<html>" + head + prologue + query + tail + "</html>"
> ```
>
> Instead, use
>
> ```
> out = "<html>%s%s%s%s</html>" % (head, prologue, query, tail)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This should be faster and easier to read imo. This is a fairly small amount of strings to concatenate, so I wouldn't concentrate to much on it :).

```
" ".join([
    "select count(*)",
    "from ept_inv e",
    "where e.ept_type =",
    str(in_row[cs.DeviceType]),
    "and e.inv_id =",
    str(in_row[cs.EndpointID]),
    ";"
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this would be premature optimization.  Just do it in the most readable/pythonic way and only optimize it if profiling with real world use cases reveals your string concatenation to be a hot spot.

Also, heed [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107188/propery-cpython-string-concatenation#comment-8512880).  :-)